# In MongoDB, is there anyway to tell what index is on a collection besides using coll.find({...}).explain()?

Tags: indexing, mongodb

I think `explain()` will tell any possible index it can use.  How about just showing all the indexes defined on the collection? (or even for the whole db?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>db.system.indexes.find();

>db.system.indexes.find( { ns: "tablename" } );
```

will give you something like

```
 { 
  "ns" : "test.fs.chunks", 
  "key" : { "files_id" : 1, "n" : 1 }, 
  "name" : "files_id_1_n_1" 
 }
```

for every index (`ns` is the collection name).

Comment: looks like the `ns:` portion needs a database name and collection name, such as `foo.analytics`

Answer (score 2):

Or use the collection name. I.e., if you have a `users` collection do:

```
db.users.getIndexes()
```